# Stop autorotation of UIViewController at creation time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

Is there any way to set autorotate behavior of an UIViewController object when it's initiated?
I wanted it to never rotate, so I tried this:

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
myViewController.shouldAutorotate = NO;
```

Seemed logical, but it doesn't work. Get the error message:

*No setter method 'setShouldAutorotate:' for assignment to property*

Or is it possible only through subclassing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should this way:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

> **Return Value**
>
> A bit mask specifying which orientations are supported.
>   See UIInterfaceOrientationMask for valid bit-mask values. The value
>   returned by this method must not be 0.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> When the user changes the device orientation, the system
>   calls this method on the root view controller or the topmost presented
>   view controller that fills the window. If the view controller supports
>   the new orientation, the window and view controller are rotated to the
>   new orientation. This method is only called if the view controller's
>   shouldAutorotate method returns YES.
>
> Override this method to report all of the orientations that the view
>   controller supports. The default values for a view controller's
>   supported interface orientations is set to
>   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and
>   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom.
>
> The system intersects the view controller's supported orientations
>   with the app's supported orientations (as determined by the Info.plist
>   file or the app delegate's
>   application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method) to
>   determine whether to rotate.

Source: [UIViewController on iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations).

Comment: OK, so you mean it's only possible through subclassing?

Comment: Yes, you have to subclass it.

Comment: I also tried this (resulting in the same error as above): UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    myViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

Comment: It's a bit disappointing if you're right. Hey Apple people: change this!